# How to get call-id in Microsoft Teams meeting app/tab

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to use the graph API like so: `POST /communications/calls/{id}/mute` to mute an ongoing call from an in-meeting teams app. This requires the `call-id`. Any idea how to obtain this id inside a Teams meeting app?

Comment: The call-id is generated when your code joins a call or receives an event a call has started. This can be done via a number of API calls.

One example is if you create a chatbot that can join calls.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft is there a way to get the call-id for an ongoing call without a bot?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT is it possible to get the id without bots?

Comment: As per documenent, Create call enables your bot to create a new outgoing peer-to-peer or group call, or join an existing meeting. You will need to register the calling bot.

Comment: When you create a call https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http, you will get an id in the response. see the response sample  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-1.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT What about the calls that were initiated by the user with GUI? How can I get the call id for those calls that I don't create using graph? What I basically want to achieve is to mute the audio output/speaker of an ongoing call which I can do using the gui in device settings.

Comment: @HM Moniruzzaman- With GUI you need to add button and call the Graph API from Backend and when you hit the Button you get the Call ID. It seems like there is no alternative for this. you need to go with above two ways to get the Call Id.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Thank you for the suggestions. As I don't have control over making the calls, the best bet would be to use a bot to join and get call id I guess. Can you tell me if the above mute API call would actually mute the audio output for the user or his mic input?

Comment: This Allows the application to mute itself.
This is a server mute, meaning that the server will drop all audio packets for this participant, even if the participant continues to stream audio.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-mute?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT yes. The suggestions help though there is no way we can get call-id for an ongoing call in a meeting. A viable solution to me looks like to join a bot and get the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding from comment section for visibility:

The call-id is generated when your code joins a call or receives an event a call has started. This can be done via a number of API calls. One example is if you create a chatbot that can join calls.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot

Comment: how the application receive a call started event?